# POSTing to a basic access authorization protected resource

Tags: node.js, post, basic-authentication

I am experiencing a problem while POSTing to a resource which is protected by basic access authentication.
Here is the code, I am using [@mikeal's request](https://github.com/mikeal/request):

```
request.post({
  uri: "http://user:password@mysite.com/resource",
  json: {
    "id": "1",
    "par1": "a",
    "par2": "b"
  }
}, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(error);
  console.log(response);
  console.log(body);
});
```

I have `{ [Error: Parse Error] bytesParsed: 0 }` in error and `undefined` in both response and body. If I remove the "user:password" part I correctly get a 401 HTTP Basic: Access denied.

Do you know if there's a way to POST JSON to a protected resource like in my case? If not, I believe I'll have to go the http module way, but I'm leaving that as a final resource since it's a lot more verbose.

UPDATE: To have this as simple as possible I've moved this file in a new directory and did a `npm install request`. The problem went away, I checked from where the `byteParsed` come from and found it's in "formidable" which is required by express, which I had in the directory where I was running this test. A bit confused right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add an header to your request with this rules:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Basically you must encode the string: username:password in base64 and add encoded string in an http header:

Authorization: Basic "Base64(username:password)"

I don't know if is possible add header with jquery or javascript. Sorry.

Look here: http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/#Transports

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I've updated my question since I've found out that moving the code to a clean directory "solves" the problem. I said "solves" because I need it in the previous folder, I think I've got some incompatibility issue. I am looking at what you linked though, for sure seems something possible.

Comment: Thanks! I've solved this doing as you suggested :D Strangely this is something the library I'm using already does, I've almost copied the solution from there, I'll look into it tonight. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

I did it like this:

```
var options = {                 
  method: 'POST',             
  uri: 'http://your.url.com/',
  form: {                  
    field1: 'somevalue',               
    field2: 666.66  
    },                       
  headers: {               
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer("username:password").toString('base64')                  
  }
};                                         
request(options, function(error, response, body) {  
  // do stuff
});
```